# Do NXT aliases expire? And when?

Tags: nxt, alias

Since NXT aliases are like domain names. Do they expire? Currently alot of people are squatting aliases and was wondering how the NXT community plan on fighting that?

Answer (score 1):

Nxt aliases do not expire now, and probably never will (since it would be unfair to change the rules after people paid for them). There is an upcoming change to allow them to be transferred, so you may then be able to buy them from squatters.

Comment: so basically if the squatter lost their account information. those alias would be lost forever.